# Accessing local variables from void functions

Tags: c++

I have two functions that read files and initialize variables containing data parsed from the files read.

These variables include several vectors, counters (line counts) and a few singular variables (string and ints).

The problem I am having is that these variables all need to be accessed in later functions, and the idea is to avoid global variables. Since the functions are void, they cannot return variables, and I have found (unlike my normal language of Python) returning multiple variables is difficult.

What is a better way to go about this?

The vectors in each of the read*() functions need to be accessed in a new function I am building. But I also need the num* variables, and the recipe & serving variables.

**EDIT: My code currently**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void readNutrients(string input_file) {
    ifstream in(input_file.c_str());

    string line;
    vector<string> nName, nUnits;
    vector<double> nAmount, nCalories;
    string name, units;
    double amount, calories;

    int numNut = 0;

    while (getline(in, line)) {
        numNut++;

        int pos = line.find(';');
        name = line.substr(0, pos);
        nName.push_back(name);

        line = line.substr(pos + 1);
        istringstream iss(line);

        iss >> amount >> units >> calories;
        nAmount.push_back(amount);
        nUnits.push_back(units);
        nCalories.push_back(calories);
    }

}

void readRecipe(string input_file) {
    ifstream in(input_file.c_str());

    string line;
    string recipe;
    vector<string> rName, rUnits;
    vector<double> rAmount;
    string name, units;
    double amount;
    double servings;

    int numIng = 0;

    while (getline(in, line)) {
        numIng++;

        if (numIng == 1) {
            int pos = line.find('\n');
            recipe = line.substr(0, pos);
        }
        else if (numIng == 2) {
            istringstream iss(line);
            iss >> servings;
        }
        else {
            istringstream iss(line);
            iss >> amount >> units >> ws;
            rAmount.push_back(amount);
            rUnits.push_back(units);

            getline(iss, name);
            rName.push_back(name);
        }
    }

}

void readFiles(string nutrientFile, string recipeFile) {
    readNutrients(nutrientFile);
    readRecipe(recipeFile);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    readFiles(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Since the functions are void, they cannot return variables" - why do they *need* to return `void`?

Comment: Have the caller pass in references to the variables.

Comment: Pass parameters that you want to return as reference, then you don't need to return it.

Comment: you should have asked this question in the morning then. It's really hard to make up a solution to an unknown problem explained with the point of view of the one that has this very problem...

Comment: @user2357112 Youll have to fill me in, brand spanking new to C++ and functions here are throwing me for a loop let alone learning syntax. Can void functions return values back from the function other than void? Or do you mean remove the void piece and declare them a type? If so, what do you declare a mixed-bag of types?

Comment: If you have that much assorted stuff you need to share between functions, consider bundling it up into an object, but also consider the possibility that you might be able to restructure your code so you don't need to share so much stuff.

Comment: I would say that maybe you need your function to not be void, and return relevant result from it. If the variable you need elsewhere is the content of the file, you should pass that file around as parameter

Comment: @GigaRohan Not familiar w/ passing in reference. If I have a void function that does something, and then once its done, another function needs to access a vector that was built in that void function, how do you pass via reference?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot there are a variety of results in the void function (vectors, ints, strings) I wouldn't know what type to declare the function! Thoughts?

Comment: For returning more then one value you can use std::tuple.

Comment: @user1438832 not using C++11 unfortunately

Comment: "If so, what do you declare a mixed-bag of types?" - you make one object bundling up all the data and return that. `std::tuple` is technically an option, but it's more usual to define your own class, with sensible attribute names and maybe methods.

Comment: @pstatix you really should update your compiler then. C++98 is nearly 20 years old.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot above is a very simplified version of what I am trying to do. My compiler is unfortunately provided by the USG...budget cuts and all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you included your code, I have a better idea of what's going on.

What you need is to create a structure that can hold the result of your parsing. Since your function is not returning anything, it's only logical that you won't have access to it's result.

I think your intent here is to have a list of nutrients read from a file, and read every nutrients from that file and fill up the list in your program.

The problem is that your program has no idea of what makes a nutrient a nutrient. You should teach him that by declaring what makes a nutrient a nutrient:

```
struct Nutrient {
    std::string name, unit;
    double amount, calories;
};
```

Then, instead of creating a bunch of lists of values, you should create a list of nutrients.

```
std::vector<Nutrient> readNutrients(std::string input_file) {
    // Here declare your vector:
    std::vector<Nutrient> nutrients;

    // declare line, calories, name...

    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        // fill your variables name calories etc...

        // create a nutrient
        Nutrient n;

        // fill the nutrient with values from the parsing.
        n.name = name;
        n.unit = units;
        n.amount = amount;
        n.calories = calories;

        // add the nutrient to the list.
        nutrients.push_back(n);
    }

    // return a filled list of nutrient.
    return nutrients;
}
```

By the way, you don't need the num* variables, since `nutrients.size()` will return you the number of nutrients in the list.

That solution goes the same with recipes: Create a type to add the concept of a recipe in your program, and use that type.

Please note that this code is not optimal, `std::move` from C++11 should will grant you enormous speed up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your case clearly. But because you can't get result as return   values of void function, it may get results by output arguments using pointers or refrence types.

for example:

```
void _read(const char* file,  vector<string>& r_list, int* pState)
{
    // do parsing file
    // do outputs
    *pState = (your_number);
    r_list.push_back("your string");
}
```

Hope this is useful for you.