# Comparing string elements of two vector<Structs>

Tags: c++, string, function, vector, struct

Follow on to my previous question here:

[Accessing local variables from void functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037546/accessing-local-variables-from-void-functions/43038058#43038058)

I've since been able to get the data I need, and now I am attempting to compare the `string name` attribute from each `struct` element passed to a function.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nutrient {
    string name, units;
    double amount, calories;
};

struct Recipe {
    string title;
    double servings;
};

struct Ingredient {
    string name, units;
    double amount;
};

vector<Nutrient> readNutrients(istream& fin) {

    vector<Nutrient> nutrients;

    /**ifstream in(input_file.c_str());*/

    string line;

    while (getline(fin, line)) {

        Nutrient n;

        int pos = line.find(';');
        n.name = line.substr(0, pos);
        line = line.substr(pos + 1);

        istringstream iss(line);

        iss >> n.amount >> n.units >> n.calories;
        nutrients.push_back(n);
    }

    return nutrients;

}

Recipe readRecipe(istream& fin) {

    Recipe recipe;

    string line;

    int lineCount = 0;

    while (getline(fin, line)) {

        lineCount++;
        istringstream iss(line);

        if (lineCount == 1) {
            iss >> recipe.title;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 2) {
            iss >> recipe.servings;
        }
    }
    return recipe;
}

vector<Ingredient> readIngredients(istream& fin) {

    vector<Ingredient> ingredients;

    string line;
    string title; // Just grabs, doesnt return
    double servings; // Just grabs, doesnt return

    int lineCount = 0;


    while (getline(fin, line)) {

        Ingredient g;

        lineCount++;
        istringstream iss(line);

        if (lineCount == 1) {
            iss >> title;
        }
        else if (lineCount == 2) {
            iss >> servings;
        }
        else {
            iss >> g.amount >> g.units >> ws;
            getline(iss, g.name, '\n');
            cout << g.name << "\n";
            ingredients.push_back(g);
        }
    }
    return ingredients;
}

bool itemsMatch(vector<Nutrient>& nut, vector<Ingredient>& ing) {
    int matchCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nut.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ing.size(); j++) {
            if (nut[i].name == ing[j].name) {
                cout << nut[i].name << " matched " << ing[j].name << endl;
                cout << "\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << nut[i].name << " didnt match " << ing[j].name << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<Nutrient> nutri;
    vector<Ingredient> ingri;
    Recipe rec;
    bool match;

    ifstream finNutr(argv[1]);
    ifstream finIngr(argv[2]);
    ifstream finReci(argv[2]);

    nutri = readNutrients(finNutr);
    ingri = readIngredients(finIngr);
    rec = readRecipe(finReci);

    match = itemsMatch(nutri, ingri);

    return 0;
}
```

The `bool itemsMatch()` is what is causing trouble. Here is the last output:

```
graham crackers
milk chocolate
marshmallows
graham crackers didnt match graham crackers
graham crackers didnt match milk chocolate
graham crackers didnt match marshmallows
milk chocolate didnt match graham crackers
milk chocolate didnt match milk chocolate
milk chocolate didnt match marshmallows
cheese, swiss didnt match graham crackers
cheese, swiss didnt match milk chocolate
cheese, swiss didnt match marshmallows
marshmallows didnt match graham crackers
marshmallows didnt match milk chocolate
marshmallows matched marshmallows
```

As visible, there are several strings that do match, but for some reason it says they do not and I am not sure why.

**arg1 content**

```
graham crackers; 2 squares 59
milk chocolate; 1 bar 235
cheese, swiss; 1 oz 108
marshmallows; 1 cup 159
```

**arg2 content**

```
S'mores
2
4 squares graham crackers
1 bar milk chocolate
2 large marshmallows
```

Comment: Step through with the debugger.

Comment: @chris the debugger? I'm not familiar with a c++ debugger. Is it built in somehow?

Comment: Depends what you're using. Most IDEs have a debugger built in and compilers come with a debugger you can use from the command line. It's well worth going through a tutorial on how to use a debugger.

Comment: Have you verified that the vectors are containing what you think they contain? Use a loop to print the contents of each, if you don't have a debugger. Also, you should edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: are nut and ing the same size vectors?

Comment: Nut and ing in test are not the same size, but in practice that need not matter. Nut may have values not in ing and vice versa. I've done the loops and pushed out the contents of the name attribute for both vectors. The are populated with correct data. The first value in each is graham cracker; when i test to see if they are equal, which they are, the above says they are not. Is this the best way to compare string elements of a vector?

Comment: On a side note, you are passing the vectors *by value* to `itemsMatch()`, so it will make duplicate copies of their data in memory. You should be passing the vectors *by reference* instead.  Also, have a look at the STL's `std::find_if()` algorithm instead of searching manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your input files have DOS line endings, which are a sequence of two chars: `"\r\n"`

When you use `getline` it will read up to the `\n` and so the `\r` gets included in the strings you read from the file. That means that your ingredients read from the second file are these strings:

```
S'mores\r
2\r
4 squares graham crackers\r
1 bar milk chocolate\r
2 large marshmallows
```

Note that this doesn't have `"\r\n"` after the last line, so "marshmallows" gets read with no `\r` carriage return character.

In the other file the ingredients are not at the end of the line, so the `\r` carriage return character doesn't get read into the `name` string for the nutrients. This means when you compare the strings you are comparing:

```
"graham crackers" == "graham crackers\r" -> false
"milk chocolate" == "milk chocolate\r" -> false
"marshmallows" == "marshmallows" -> true
```

The solution is to either strip the `\r` carriage returns manually, or convert your input files to remove the carriage returns (or stop using Windows, which has this stupid convention and causes endless problems for beginners).

To remove the `\r` characters you can do this after each `getline`:

```
while (getline(fin, line)) {
    if (!line.empty() && line.back() == '\r')
        line.pop_back();
```

This will remove a `\r` from the end of the line if it's present.

Or if you're stuck in the past and can't use C++11:

```
while (getline(fin, line)) {
    if (!line.empty() && line[line.length()-1] == '\r')
        line.resize(line.length()-1);
```

Comment: Last night before I gave up for the evening, I ran a simple `ing[x].name.length()` and figured out that there were hidden characters; but I was tired and was going to look up the solution tonight. Ill try this tonight and should it work give answer and upvote!

Comment: It works :) I already tested it to confirm that it explains the behaviour you see, and that it fixes it.

Comment: Excellent! Running program with fake data eventually lead me to the conclusion that it had to be the data in the vector; and it only failed on the `name` attribute, so this was the most logical result.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison code you posted is *fine*. Of course your function will always return true, which doesn't make sense, but this is not the problem.

The problem is in the data of your structs, so either the data (e.g. the files you read from) or the code that you use to read the data to your structs is flawed.

Either print your structs to confirm that they contain exactly what you think they do (of course print the size of your vectors) or use a **debugger**, for example the *gdb*.

---

Pro tip: Not the problem here, but consider changing your prototype:

```
bool itemsMatch(vector<Nutrient> nut, vector<Ingredient> ing)
```

to this:

```
bool itemsMatch(vector<Nutrient>& nut, vector<Ingredient>& ing)
```

so that instead of *copying* the whole vectors, you just pass a reference to them, which for big vector is so much faster! =)

Comment: thanks for the tip with reference passing. I've posted my full code to see if somebody see's something I don't see. I'm starting to wonder if its around the part where I use `getline(iss, g.name, '\n')` that the values aren't truly matching or something.

Comment: @pstatix I now saw it, but it seems you found the answer! Glad I helped, and +1 for your question! :)

Answer (score -2):

You should change the code like this and then test, check the syntax of my code i didn't test :)

```
auto itring = ing.begin();

for (auto itrnut = nut.begin(); itrnut != nut.end(); itrnut++, itring++ ) {
            if (itrnut->name == itring->name) {
                cout << itrnut->name << " matched " << itring->name << endl;
                cout << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: And wrong or not, it's not very helpful to just say "change your code to this". Why? What's wrong with the original and how does this fix it?